# Enlarge a Windows Form GMAPS.NET Image

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I have a GMAPS.NET map on my Windows Form zommed in to Level 18. I am looking to enlarge that zoomed image to fill the control bounds (enlarge the existing image - not zoom).

Is there a method for doing this within GMAPS.NET?

Cheers!

Comment: if the GMap control is docked (within the container) - then it will enlarge, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah it does. My problem though is that I want to enlarge the image contained within the control rather than zoom.

Comment: Well, just adjust the zoom on form resize event.